# Why is an empty __set() method slower than one that does work?

Tags: php, magic-methods, microbenchmark

I was toying around with PHP magic methods (specifically [Property overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)), and, while micro-benchmarking, encountered a quirk I'm having trouble explaining:

It seems that a `__set` method with an empty body takes more time to run than one which does work. The below code snippet demonstrates this:

```php
class EmptySetter {
    public function __set($name, $value) {}
}

class NonEmptySetter {
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->{$name} = $value;
    }
}

function benchmark($obj) {
    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++) {
        $obj->foo = 42;
    }
    return microtime(TRUE) - $start_time;
}

printf("EmptySetter: %.2f seconds\n", benchmark(new EmptySetter));
printf("NonEmptySetter: %.2f seconds\n", benchmark(new NonEmptySetter));

// output (on my Core 2 Duo laptop):
// EmptySetter: 4.39 seconds
// NonEmptySetter: 1.28 seconds
```

Does anyone have an explanation as to why this is happening?

Comment: Does it matter? Do you ever get 10 million consecutive visits? Also, why on earth would you use an empty magic method? Benchmarks are only meaningful if applied to real-world situations. This is a contrived example.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, it doesn't matter, but very interesting :^ )

Comment: @sectus It is only interesting if you are interested in the C implementation of PHP. Performance-wise it is only useful if you use empty magic methods 10 million times... (And a correction to my previous comment: I meant to say "consecutive calls to the method". I do not know why I used "consecutive visits" as an example.)

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, so, the deal is not in C implementation of PHP, it is wrong test implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, i see it's wrong testing case.

After first loop `NonEmptySetter` would has new public property `foo`. Next loops do not call `__set` method at all, they use public property.

```
class NonEmptySetter {
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        echo 'called only once'; // would be echoed only once.
        $this->{$name} = $value;
    }
}
```

Valid test

```
class EmptySetter {
    public function __set($name, $value) {}
}

class NonEmptySetter {
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->{$name} = $value;
    }
}

function benchmark($class_name) {
    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
        $obj = new $class_name();
        $obj->foo = 42;
    }
    return microtime(TRUE) - $start_time;
}

printf("NonEmptySetter: %.2f seconds\n", benchmark('NonEmptySetter'));
printf("EmptySetter: %.2f seconds\n", benchmark('EmptySetter'));
```

http://3v4l.org/gVtSq

Empty setter is faster.

Comment: Faster at what exactly? `EmptySetter::$foo` doesn't exist.

Comment: @TOOTSKI, we do not need to check equality of this pieces of code(they are not). I just said that first peace of code is faster than second whatever they do.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare these two, because the end result is not equal.

```
$o1 = (new NonEmptySetter);
$o1->foo = 42;

$o2 = (new EmptySetter);
$o2->foo = 42;

var_dump($o1, $o2, $o2->foo);
```

This gives:

```
object(NonEmptySetter)[1]
  public 'foo' => int 42

object(EmptySetter)[2]

null
```

And plus a notice for the last one: `Notice: Undefined property: EmptySetter::$foo`

That means the **property is never set**, it doesn't exist, fairy dust, I'm assuming the irregularities there take time.

[image]

If you declare your class properly (note the `$foo`):

```
class EmptySetter {
    public $foo = NULL;
    public function __set($name, $value) {}
}
```

#### Timings would be tied: [Your benchmark with EmptySetter::$foo declared](http://3v4l.org/OfJgh#v560beta1)